# Proposing an alternative way of securing ajax calls with a stored token

Tags: ajax, security

Now I think securing ajax calls, sometimes normal forms with a token is pretty common. It works like this. 1) The user requests a page 2) a token is put into the html, and into the session 3) on submit these values are checked.

Now one major obstacle I am facing with this is caching. I do not have a lot of changing content, so I want to be able to cache for at least 24 hours. On the other hand, I do some ajax calls on the front-end, and good practice is to have them a little secured.

Now I was thinking of this, but I do not know if it will work. Maybe you can help.

- user requests a site, and the cached site is given.
- On the site, the first ajax call is made, which only asks a token
- In the backend, a token is generated, stored in the session and sent to the front-end
- The token is stored in a var in the frontend, and now sent with every call
- On every call we check the session and the given token
- If they match we do our DB stuff, if not we make a call to the FBI
- The FBI takes over the case

Just kidding about the last part. But will this work, because you are not sending a piece of the actual website.

Maybe you can make it a little smarter by storing an identifier of the form the user requests.

Actually, I have no idea if this will work, I actually doubt it. Maybe someone can explain to me why this will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to [prevent csrf](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet) with a token,  each user must have a unique token that an attacker cannot guess.  If you serve the same cached page to everyone,  then the token isn't a secret and an attacker can forge requests.

That being said. You could have some JavaScript use an XHR to pull that users token from the user's session data store and populate a form or in ajax calls.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will try and implement this in my system then. Are there any other ways to work with cached files?

Comment: @Saif Bechan  the files could be cached per user, but that could get large.  Checking the referer is on the CSRF prevention cheat sheet,  its considered a weaker form of prevention.  Also the lack of a referer should be a failure.  You should read that link.